# Paypal Api access features

Tags: paypal

Since  Paypal officially sends people here for  support, I hope  StackOverflow members  will not  burn me at the stake.

**After the  product is sold, I need in the paypal confirmation email**

- Temporary password  sent so user can login to site with their Email and that password.
- We will obviously need that email/password via api to authenticate user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify Paypal's confirmation email, given Paypal's API restrictions. However, you can send emails via your application, to your users upon successful payment.

PayPal will send you application a response code for each transaction (payment successful/unsuccessful), which you can use to handle your behavior.

Comment: I   thought that was the  way, and the challenge we have is this is a membership.  Our server generated email  at (many) times ends in spam box, no matter how hard we try. And then people don't see the login info, and cancel the  membership

Comment: Yea, you might wanna look into this great answer on serverfault to avoid your mails going to spam: [http://serverfault.com/a/48439]